# Using the phrase "I dread to think " in past tense

Tags: word-usage, past-tense

I searched the Internet widely but I can only find the phrase "I dread to think" in present form. Could it be used in past tense as: "He dreaded to think what might happen next."

Dread as the main verb.

Comment: Yes it can be used in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's correct.**

> "He dreaded to think what might happen next."

*Dreaded* is the only word that can be changed to its past tense form. Since changing either think and happen to its past tense form makes this,

> "He dread to thought what might happen next."

and

> "He dread to think what might happened next."

As you can see, both sound utterly wrong and are grammatically incorrect. Although you can also use dreads, which makes the sentence sound natural. Which makes,

> "He dreads to think what might happen next."

The word **might** can also be changed to its past tense form

> "He dread to think what might have happened next."

Overall, you can choose what you'll use out of these 2 phrases,

> "He **dreads** to think what *might have* **happened** next."

or

> "He **dreaded** to think what *might have* **happened** next."

- Regular verbs' of past tense and past participle are formed using/adding the **ed** form.

Comment: @Sorryl'mDumb what difference does "might have happened" make to the sentence?

Comment: Secondly, is it must to use "dreaded" and "might have" together in the sentence? Does using only "dreaded" is wrong or sound unnatural?

Comment: Oh, sorry I was offline. Adding both *dreaded* and *might have happened* makes the sentence look much richer and natural. No, it doesn't have to use both words. Your sentence was correct, mine was just a choice.